# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION Swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to make an app that will tell the time remaining until a specific date. Like some alarm apps say how much time until it will wake you up. I was having issues with ways of calculating this so I created my own function for it. My ***original version*** on a ***playground*** seemed to be working fine:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"


let Test = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(NSCalendarUnit.Day, fromDate: NSDate())

func Calculation() {

    //Months
    var month: String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    }

    print(month)

    //Days
    var day: String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    }

    print(day)


    //Hours
    var hour: String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    }

    print(hour)

    //Minutes
    var minute: String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    }

    print(minute)

    //Current Time
    let CurrentMonths = Int(month)
    let CurrentDays = Int(day)
    let CurrentHours = Int(hour)
    let CurrentMinutes = Int(minute)

    //End Date
    let EndMonths = 11;
    let EndDays = 23;
    let EndHours = 12;
    let EndMinutes = 60;

    //Calculation

    var LeftMonths = EndMonths - CurrentMonths!
    var LeftDays = EndDays - CurrentDays! - 1
    var LeftHours = EndHours - CurrentHours! - 1
    var LeftMinutes = EndMinutes - CurrentMinutes! - 1

    //Update Labels



    //Re-Run Loop To Update Time
}
Calculation()
```

I had to change it a little so it would work as a standalone iOS app in Swift 2. Currently I have the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` In the console it says

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) `. I checked the debug menu/console to the left of it and none of my variables are set to `nil.
```

Here is my ViewController.swift code ***UPDATED CODE To Fix Local Var Problem***:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Current Time
    var CurrentMonths:Int = 0
    var CurrentDays:Int = 0
    var CurrentHours:Int = 0
    var CurrentMinutes:Int = 0

    //End Date
    var EndMonths:Int = 0
    var EndDays:Int = 0
    var EndHours:Int = 0
    var EndMinutes:Int = 0

    //Calculation

    var LeftMonths:Int = 0
    var LeftDays:Int = 0
    var LeftHours:Int = 0
    var LeftMinutes:Int = 0

    //Define
    var month:String = ""
    var day:String = ""
    var hour:String = ""
    var minute:String = ""

    //Labels
    @IBOutlet weak var DayL: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var HourL: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var MinuteL: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        Calculation()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Months
    func Month() {
        var month: String {
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
            return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        }
        print(month)
        Day()
    }

    //Days
    func Day() {
        var day: String {
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
            return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        }
        print(day)
        Hour()
    }

    //Hours
    func Hour() {
        var hour: String {
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh"
            return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        }
        print(hour)
        Minute()
    }
    //Minutes
    func Minute() {
        var minute: String {
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm"
            return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        }
        print(minute)
    }

    func Calculation() {

        //Start Calculations
        Month()

        //Current Time
        CurrentMonths = Int(month)!
        CurrentDays = Int(day)!
        CurrentHours = Int(hour)!
        CurrentMinutes = Int(minute)!

        //End Date
        EndMonths = 11;
        EndDays = 23;
        EndHours = 12;
        EndMinutes = 60;

        //Calculation

        LeftMonths = EndMonths - CurrentMonths
        LeftDays = EndDays - CurrentDays - 1
        LeftHours = EndHours - CurrentHours - 1
        LeftMinutes = EndMinutes - CurrentMinutes - 1

        //Update Labels
        DayL.text = String(LeftDays)
        HourL.text = String(LeftHours)
        MinuteL.text = String(LeftMinutes)



        //Re-Run Loop To Update Time
        Calculation()
    }

}
```

The error occurs on `CurrentMonths = Int(month)!`
All of the solutions from similar problems have not seem to work.
Also, when removing the var tag in the functions in the Calculation function, it gives me an error so I can't remove it.

Comment: `month` is the empty string, therefore `Int(month)` returns `nil` ...

Comment: but I set it in the Calculations function.

Comment: It does not appear that you are calling any of those functions you are creating (`Month`, `Day`, `Hour`, `Minute`), so @MartinR is correct.

Comment: @Fman: Use the debugger. Set breakpoints and check the variables ... The *computed property* `month` is local to the `Month()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having scope problems in your `Calculation()` function.

If you want to run `Month()`, `Day()`, `Hour()`, etc. in `Calculation()`, call them from the `Calculation()` scope.  Those functions should be declared from the class level, instead of in `Calculation()`.

Additionally, you're not setting your class variables `Month`, `Day`, etc after calculating them in each function.

Here is your complete code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Current Time
    var CurrentMonths:Int = 0
    var CurrentDays:Int = 0
    var CurrentHours:Int = 0
    var CurrentMinutes:Int = 0

    //End Date
    var EndMonths:Int = 0
    var EndDays:Int = 0
    var EndHours:Int = 0
    var EndMinutes:Int = 0

    //Calculation

    var LeftMonths:Int = 0
    var LeftDays:Int = 0
    var LeftHours:Int = 0
    var LeftMinutes:Int = 0

    //Define
    var month:String = ""
    var day:String = ""
    var hour:String = ""
    var minute:String = ""

    //Labels
    @IBOutlet weak var DayL: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var HourL: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var MinuteL: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        Calculation()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func Month() {
        var month: String {
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM"
            return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        }
        self.month = month
        Day()
    }

    //Days
    func Day() {
        var day: String {
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
            return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        }
        self.day = day
        Hour()
    }

    //Hours
    func Hour() {
        var hour: String {
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh"
            return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        }
        self.hour = hour
        Minute()
    }
    //Minutes
    func Minute() {
        var minute: String {
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm"
            return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        }
        self.minute = minute
    }


    func Calculation() {

        //Months
        Month()

        //Current Time
        CurrentMonths = Int(month)!
        CurrentDays = Int(day)!
        CurrentHours = Int(hour)!
        CurrentMinutes = Int(minute)!

        //End Date
        EndMonths = 11;
        EndDays = 23;
        EndHours = 12;
        EndMinutes = 60;

        //Calculation

        LeftMonths = EndMonths - CurrentMonths
        LeftDays = EndDays - CurrentDays - 1
        LeftHours = EndHours - CurrentHours - 1
        LeftMinutes = EndMinutes - CurrentMinutes - 1

        //Update Labels
        DayL.text = String(LeftDays)
        HourL.text = String(LeftHours)
        MinuteL.text = String(LeftMinutes)



        //Re-Run Loop To Update Time
        Calculation()
    }

}
```

Comment: it doesn't solve the error, I moved all of the Month, day, etc functions outside the Calculations function and had Calculations call the first one like you did but the same error occurs at the same place.

Comment: @Fman You're also not setting your class variables after creating calculating the local variables for Month, Day, etc.  I've corrected that in my answer.

Comment: I should also not that you code will infinitely look, since you're calling `Calculation()` inside of itself.  If you're looking for a way to update a label based on time, I'd look into NSTimer.

Comment: Thank you, after commenting out `Calculations()` it fixed a death loop issue and your code worked perfectly!

Comment: Yep infinitely loop, glad you figured it out.